# Canonicals for Python: are objects with the same id() the same object, `is` operator, unbound method objects

Tags: discussion, canonical

We need a Python canonical for the following category of questions, but the titles are pretty non-obvious and search-resistant, so we also need more dupe targets to be identified (or written). **What should our canonicals and dupes be?**

Current canonicals:

1. [Unnamed Python objects have the same id()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802740/unnamed-python-objects-have-the-same-id)
2. [How can two Python objects have same id() but 'is' operator returns False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893267/how-can-two-python-objects-have-same-id-but-is-operator-returns-false)
3. [python bound and unbound method object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/python-bound-and-unbound-method-object)

   - one frequently-used canonical. Non-obvious wording. Body references `id()`. Does not reference `is` operator.

Some of the many other questions:

1. [Why do methods of different objects of same class have same id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727490/why-do-methods-of-different-objects-of-same-class-have-same-id) - not yet closed as duplicate
2. [Weird id() behaviour; different ids, yet id(x) == id(y) returns True? [duplicate of 3.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729316/weird-id-behaviour-different-ids-yet-idx-idy-returns-true?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [is operator not working on objects with same identity? [duplicate of 1,3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907032/is-operator-not-working-on-objects-with-same-identity?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. ... many others ...

Principles:

- two different objects can have the same `id()` if their lifetimes do not overlap; first one then the second happen to be temporarily created at the same `id()` address. This causes lots of grief:

  - one common example is Python method objects (which are temporary objects constructed to allow calling a method on a specific instance. Internally, Python uses a descriptor protocol to wrap the function in a method object each time). So `id(obj.meth)` is always the id of a temporary object.
  - a second example is any temporary expressions created but not assigned
  - hence a common mistake pattern is to take `id1 = id(temp1); id2 = id(temp2)` then check if `id1 == id2` and wrongly conclude that `temp1` must be the same as `temp2`
- `is` is more reliable (and pessimistic) in evaluating `x is y`, both objects are alive at the same time, so `is` returns False unless they really are the same object

Comment: The Python chat room maintains many canonicals and would welcome discussions like these: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python

Answer (score 2):

There are actually only two distinct questions here:

1. `id()` vs `is` -- how they are related, if comparing `id()`s is safe
2. `id()`s of bound and unbound methods -- due to their unusual semantics and lifetimes, they give confusing results

   - This can be mentioned in 1) to illustrate why comparing `id()`s is generally unsafe

I've clarified the title of [id()s of bound and unbound method objects --- sometimes the same for different objects, sometimes different for the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/ids-of-bound-and-unbound-method-objects-sometimes-the-same-for-different-o) to make it carry the gist of the subject to cover 2) and written [id() vs `is` operator. Is it safe to compare `id`s? Does the same `id` mean the same object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268343/id-vs-is-operator-is-it-safe-to-compare-ids-does-the-same-id-mean-the/52268344#52268344) for 1) since none of the listed questions covered the topic as a whole.

Comment: That's only true if the user already knows that an unbound method object is temporarily created (and thus unsafe to take id() of), and also that an unnamed expression is temporarily created (and thus unsafe to take id() of). All users start off not knowing this, hence it manifests as multiple different issues.

Comment: @smci yes, but I hope I've catched the gist of all the visible symptoms in the titles to make them googlable.

Comment: ivan, only for advanced users; new users won't understand what the words mean. So we'll need lots of coverage from duplicates which we close into them or link to them.

Comment: @smci duplicates exist and are preserved specifically for cases when a user has ["the uncanniest ability to ask the same exact question using zero words in common"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions#comment82604_37478). You cannot predict those. A canonical's job is to be 1) easily googable by _relevant_ keywords; 2) fully cover the topic so that so further posts are required.

Comment: We're not disagreeing; I said establishing good canonicals is only part of the battle. I said we also need lots of coverage from duplicates. Which we don't yet have. Both concrete and abstract duplicates.

Comment: @smci I'm not sure what else you want me to do here...

Comment: I wasn't asking you to do anything else, just commenting this is not the end. Although when I reread this answer, I'd modify *"There are actually only two distinct questions here..."* to *"...once you learn that in Python, unnamed expressions and unbound method objects are temporarily allocated"*. Otherwise it sounds very dismissive of the learning curve and the number of pitfalls this manifests as.